# check if last item in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I will have this bool function checking if containing record is last record from the table and working on the basis of its `true` `false` result.

```
 public bool IsLast(int? id) {
            var islastcard = (from u in db.CardTables
                               where u.CardID == id 
                               select u);
            var alllist = (from u in db.CardTables
                            select u).ToList();
            if (islastcard.Equals(alllist[alllist.Count - 1])) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

It checks whether record `islastcard` is last from table `alllist` and if it is last or not then I am Working according to these bool results-

```
var uploadedfile = (from u in db.CardTables
                                where u.CardID == cardtable.cardID
                                select new CardModel {
                                    cardID = cardtable.cardID,
                                    }).SingleOrDefault();
            if (IsLast(uploadedfile.cardID)) {
                ViewBag.lastitem = true;
            }
            else {
                ViewBag.lastitem = false;
            }
```

But this check always returns me `false`.

How do I match whether `islastcard` record is last from list `alllist` or not?

Comment: Are lambda expressions allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your `islastcard` is an `IEnumerable` that contains your card, not the card itself. If you add a call of `Single` to it, your code should work:

```
var last = islastcard.SingleOrDefault()
return last != null && last.Equals(alllist[alllist.Count - 1]));
```

Your code remains grossly inefficient, though, because you retrieve the entire list, check its last itmem, and then discard it. Moreover, you instantiate card objects for something that can be checked based on their IDs.

A better approach would be checking the ID of the last item directly, like this:

```
public bool IsLast(int? id) {
    return id == db.CardTables.Select(c => c.CardID).LastOrDefault();
}
```